# StreamReader encoding not recognizing degree character

Tags: c#, streamreader, iso-8859-1

Thanks in advance for your help.

I have an ASP.NET Core web application (running on my Mac) Controller method receiving a CSV file (created in Excel, saved as CSV) encoded with "iso-8859-1" (I've tried specifying UTF8 and a couple other). I can tell the encoding by running this command in Terminals: file -I "[fileName]".

When I use StreamReader and specify "iso-8859-1", the 'degree' character isn't being set properly when I inspect the 'content' variable; when I look at it in my Local window, I can see that the degree character looks like an upside down exclamation mark.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream(), 
       Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Decoded text (please note that the upside down exclamation marks should be degree character):

```
Description,ManufacturerPartNumber\r\"50a,10%,-55¡C~125¡C\",123
```

[Img of code, with decoded text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/degV2.png)

Thanks for the help!

Cheers, 
Dan

EDIT: 
Here's the byte code from my 'reader' variable (StreamReader):
68,101,115,99,114,105,112,116,105,111,110,44,77,97,110,117,102,97,99,116,117,114,101,114,80,97,114,116,78,117,109,98,101,114,13,34,67,45,88,55,82,44,48,46,49,117,70,44,48,54,48,51,44,53,48,86,44,49,48,37,44,45,53,53,161,67,126,49,50,53

Comment: Sorry, didn't post my question: How can I get the degree character to appear properly in my 'content' variable?  If someone uploads a file not encoded in "iso-8859-1", do I need to check the file encoding?

Comment: Have you tried *round-tripping* a string containing just a degree symbol using that iso-8859-1 encoding?

Comment: Can you share the raw byte code values in the CSV file, e.g. as a Base64 encoded string, that we could use as a [mcve] to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks @dbc. You mean returning a CSV file with the degree symbol to the caller?

Comment: I mean, can you [edit] your question to somehow share the byte codes of a portion of the CSV file containing a degree symbol, so we can begin to try to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks again, I added the bytes to the ticket

Comment: Your file (from Excel?) contains 161 where you expect the ° instead. According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1 or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252 you'd want a 176 there.
How did you generate the file? How did you input that °?

Comment: Try Windows-1252 encoding

Comment: Thanks!  @BenjaminPodszun, I got the CSV file from my client; I just asked him how he got that into the CSV.

Comment: Thanks! @Gaurang Dave, I tried using WIndows-1252, but it throw an error: "'Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name. For information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for the Encoding.RegisterProvider method."

Comment: to get Windows-1252 you need `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);`

Comment: To get Windows-1252 encoding working, I had to install the CodePages NuGet pkg and add this line of code: Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);   But the degree symbol is still coming through incorrectly.  Any other ideas?  Is something wrong with my encoding?

Comment: Thanks everyone for the advice!  After a LOT of headaches, I think I found my issue!  Excel for Mac2011 (yes, it's old, but seems to work) was saving line breaks and special characters (like a degree symbol) with odd encoding, I'm guessing special for a Mac.  I could see that the original CSV used plain line breaks when inspecting/opening the file with Terminals, but when Excel saved it, the line breaks looked like ^M  (instead of plain old linebreaks visible in Terminals) and degree symbole of <A1> instead of <B0>. I downloaded a Mac app called Table Tool that simply saves in UTF-8.